# Why can't GCC optimize out `std::sqrt`?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

I have the simple program:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        std::sqrt(i);
}
```

[Clang 3.8](https://godbolt.org/g/YImj7o) optimizes it out at `-O3`, but [gcc 6.1](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm',source:'%23include+%3Ccmath%3E%0A%0A//+void+foo(void)%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%09for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+50%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A%09%09std::sqrt(i)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) doesn't. It produces the following assembly:

```
## Annotations in comments added after the question was answered,
## for the benefit of future readers.
main:
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    jmp     .L2
.L4:
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0         # break cvtsi2sd's false dep on the old value of xmm0
    pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1         # xmm1 = 0.0
    cvtsi2sd        %ebx, %xmm0  # xmm0 = (double)i
    ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm1         # scalar double comparison, setting flags
    ja      .L7                  # if (0.0 > (double)i) sqrt(i);   // The `a` = above.  AT&T syntax reverses the order, but it's jump if  xmm1 above xmm0
.L2:
    addl    $1, %ebx             # i++
    cmpl    $50, %ebx
    jne     .L4                  # i != 50
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    ret                          # return 0
.L7:
    call    sqrt                 # only executed on i < 0.  Otherwise gcc knows std::sqrt has no side effects.
    jmp     .L2
```

If I understand the *as-if* rule properly, the compiler is allowed to optimize out code that doesn't change the observable behavior of the program, which includes I/O writes, etc. I discard the result of `std::sqrt` and don't do any I/O. Furthermore, I don't have `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS` in my program. Does `std::sqrt` have observable side effects or is there another reason why GCC doesn't optimize out the call?

---

(The initial version of this question had an upper bound of `10e50`, making it an infinite loop.  The same thing happens `50`, so nvm the comments about that.)

Comment: Compiler does not know what std::sqrt does exactly. It can assume that it does perform I/O or has some other side effect. How it can be dropped? I believe the behavior of Clang is wrong and gcc is correct

Comment: @Michael `std::sqrt` is part of the implementation, so the compiler can know what it does.

Comment: @nwp The number is irrelevant, but I'll edit it.

Comment: `sqrt` probably has a highly optimized assembler implementation that makes it hard for gcc to proof that it has no side effects.

Comment: It does with -ffast-math. Without that, sqrt can set errno (edit: wait, was that only the C square root? e2: ok std::sqrt also), so perhaps it could not see (or didn't try to see) that it would not.

Comment: Who cares? You wouldn't write this code.

Comment: @nwp The compiler needn't analyze the implementation of `sqrt`. stdlib's `memmove` also has a highly optimized assembler implementation, yet the compiler can and does replace it with custom code.

Comment: `-fno-math-errno`?

Comment: Why is the sky blue? This is one of many, many cases where one or more compilers won't optimize perfectly (or even necessarily well). If this is a real issue in a real program, you could file a bug.

Comment: Compiler optimizations are only as good as the people who write them. And the people who write them care more about common cases rather than corner cases. I consider this a corner case since very few people will *intentionally* write non-trivial blocks of dead code.

Comment: @Mysticial The real code was benchmarking an iterative algorithm dealing only with looping/addition/subtraction and another that had sqrt in it. My intent was to see if using floating point despite it requiring no loops would cause any significant slowdown in the program. I discovered that `sqrt` was the sole factor preventing optimizations, hence the question. IMO iterating a code, no matter how trivial is very common in benchmarking applications. So I don't consider it to be a corner case at all.

Comment: @user6292850 You're taking my comment out of context. I said, "dead code". Not "iterating code". Please show the real code then. Because what you have here isn't real so there's no reason for the compiler to go the extra mile to fix it. (IOW, not representative of the real thing.)

Comment: `int M2(int k) { return floor(sqrt(2.0 * k + 1.0/4) - 1.0/2); }` `for (int i = 0; i < ...; ++i) { M2(i); }` Very little difference from what you see in the question.

Comment: Also `std::sqrt(0)` in a loop *is* dead code, but not `std::sqrt(i)`.

Comment: @user6292850 Technically, your `sqrt(i)` is really just `sqrt()` for 0 - 49 - which shouldn't have any side-effects and therefore is dead-code. But compiler needs to prove that by either by 1) unrolling the loop. Or 2) doing some sort of range or domain analysis. `10e50` is far too much to unroll. If you pick 50, the GCC no longer has the sqrt in there. In any case, the range/domain analysis is IMO, asking a bit much of the compiler. They can sometimes do it, and other times not.

Comment: Also, the compiler can only remove the sqrt() in your original loop if the loop-count is a small compile-time constant.

Comment: @Mysticial In both cases `10e50` was an arbitrary number chosen for the question and `50` was edited in because one person complained it was undefined behavior.

Comment: Not all optimizers are the same.

Answer (score 12):

This is somewhat related to loop unrolling.

```
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 16; ++i)  // CHANGED NUMBER OF ITERATIONS
    std::sqrt(i);
}
```

is replaced with a `return 0;` (`g++ -O3 -fdump-tree-all`).

If you take a look at `.115t.cunroll` you can see that the code is initially transformed into something like:

```
// ...

<bb 6>:
i_30 = i_22 + 1;
_32 = (double) i_30;
if (_32 < 0.0)
  goto <bb 7>;
else
  goto <bb 8>;

<bb 7>:
__builtin_sqrt (_32);

<bb 8>:
i_38 = i_30 + 1;
_40 = (double) i_38;
if (_40 < 0.0)
  goto <bb 9>;
else
  goto <bb 10>;

<bb 9>:
__builtin_sqrt (_40);

// ...
```

and the compiler, with actual numbers, can "prove" that each call to `sqrt` doesn't have side effects (`.125t.vrp2`):

```
// ...

<bb 6>:
i_30 = 3;
_32 = 3.0e+0;
if (_32 < 0.0)
  goto <bb 7>;
else
  goto <bb 8>;

<bb 7>:
__builtin_sqrt (_32);

<bb 8>:
i_38 = 4;
_40 = 4.0e+0;
if (_40 < 0.0)
  goto <bb 9>;
else
  goto <bb 10>;

<bb 9>:
__builtin_sqrt (_40);

// ...
```

If the number of iterations is large, gcc:

- doesn't perform loop unrolling (unless forced with something like `--param max-completely-peeled-insns=x` `--param max-completely-peel-times=y`)
- isn't "smart enough" to determine that a call to `sqrt(i)` doesn't have side effects (but a small help is enough, e.g. `std::sqrt(std::abs(i))`).

Also gcc (v6.x) doesn't support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS` <del>so it must assume that this pragma is ON (otherwise the generated code can be incorrect)</del> (the situation is more complex, see [bug 34678](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34678) and [Tavian Barnes' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117809/why-cant-gcc-optimize-out-stdsqrt/37119635#comment61820075_37119635)).

Comment: "Also gcc (v6.x) doesn't support #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS so it must assume that this pragma is ON"  I wish this were true but it is not.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29186 https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8100

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the standard requires to set `errno` in case `sqrt` is passed a negative number. Apparently for the value 50 (too much for unrolling) g++ "forgets" that negative values are not possible and for small values instead unrolls and discovers in each single case by constant propagation that no need of setting `errno` may arise.

Also taking the absolute value before calling `sqrt` apparently ensures g++ that it's impossible to have a negative argument to pass.

Comment: IIRC the standard **allows** setting errno but doesn't require it.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: "May" set `errno` if the input is `NaN`. Sets `errno` if the input is a negative number.

Comment: What standard is that? In C11, this depends on `math_errhandling&MATH_ERRNO`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: g++ 7.2.1 20171128 sets `errno` if you compute the sqrt of a negative number and do not specify `-fno-math-errno` and of course appropriately reports `math_errhandling` with value 3. Previously the request was more simply mandating setting `errno` for all domain errors. I'm not saying it was a good idea (IMO was a terrible idea) but it's the way it was mandated. On the bright side apparently the extra `ucomisd + ja` generated doesn't take much time as it's never taken if you don't compute square roots of negative numbers. The code executed in that case is however quite ugly...